# How to change value in a class with a prototype method?

Tags: javascript, class, bind

In the code below I'm trying to change the value of the property isTired to true using the prototype method .rest. When I call it with either mommy.rest() or mommy.rest.bind(mommy) it turns isTired to true. If I call mommy.isTired immediately after it results to true.

However, if I delete the call, it turns the value false. I was looking through other stack overflow responses and I believe this can be solved by using bind. I've read MDM but just can't seem to find a way to retain the value.

```
var SuperHero = function() {
    this.isTired = false;
}

SuperHero.prototype.rest = function() {
    this.isTired = true;
    console.log(this.isTired)
}

var SuperHuman = function(greeting) {
  SuperHero.call(this)
    this.greeting = greeting;
    this.speed = 'normal';
}

SuperHuman.prototype = Object.create(SuperHero.prototype)
SuperHuman.prototype.constructor = SuperHuman
var mommy = new SuperHuman('hola')


var mom = mommy.rest.bind(mommy)
mom() // -> outputs true
mommy.isTired //-> outputs true if I keep mom(), but if i delete it it turns false
```

Comment: you are not calling the rest() if you are commenting the mom(). mommy.rest.bind(mommy) ! = mommy.rest()

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly right but you're getting mixed up at the end.

Everything after the first line is wrong.

```
var mommy = new SuperHuman('hola')

var mom = mommy.rest.bind(mommy)
// mom() // -> outputs true
mommy.isTired //-> outputs true if I keep mom(), but if i delete it it turns false
```

Just do this:

```
var mommy = new SuperHuman('hola')
mommy.rest();
// mommy.isTired is now true
```

As long as your reference to `mommy` exists, `isTired` will remain true until/unless another function changes it.

Using `bind` does nothing for you in this situation. All `bind` does is execute a function in the context of a different `this`. That doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do with

```
var mom = mommy.rest.bind(mommy)
```

is that you are setting (bind) a new context `this` to the function rest(). So in `rest()` the type of `this === Superhuman` which the value is `mommy` object.

When you call `mom()` it invokes the `rest()` then sets `this.isTired = true;` else `this.isTired = false;`

If you want to call `rest()`, you would `mommy.rest();`. Pretty simple